# AngularJS load different css files depending on locale

Tags: css, angularjs, internationalization

I've got a multilingual application that supports Farsi and English, as you might know farsi is RTL, so I used a css-flipper in my gulp files to create another version of my whole css files in rtl, my problems is that i cannot inject them (with gulp-inject, for obvious reasons!) so I have to manually insert them to my index.html
What is the best way to do this?
currently I use angular-css to add css files depending on my locale (I use angular-local) in it's constructor (I used typescript with Swiip's angular generator)

Also, I should be able to remove ltr css file and add rtl css file and vice versa

```
export class MainController {
    private $translate: angular.translate.ITranslateProvider;
    private $css;

    public constructor($translate: angular.translate.ITranslateProvider, $css: Object) {
        this.$translate = $translate;
        this.$css = $css;
        if (this.getLang() === 'en') {
        this.$css.add('app/index.min.css');
        } else {
            this.$css.add('app/index.rtl.min.css');
        }
    }

    public getLang() {
        return this.$translate.use();
    }

    public changeLang() {
        if (this.getLang() === 'fa') {
            this.$translate.use('en');
            this.$css.remove('app/index.rtl.min.css');
            this.$css.add('app/index.min.css');
        } else {
            this.$translate.use('fa');
            this.$css.remove('app/index.min.css');
            this.$css.add('app/index.rtl.min.css');
        }
    }
}
```